# Why I am banned for reviewing?

Tags: support

I did not pass [this](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/467662) review audit.

I voted "Looks OK". I do not see anything criminal there. The answer is badly formatted but is not even incorrect. And I am always notified by moderators that incorrect answers are not a reason to flag them as bad quality.

The answer got 1 downvote and was deleted by the owner.

And I do not remember that I did not pass many review audits. Maybe another one in the last two days. And passed LOTS of this kind of audits.

So what is the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That particular answer was an unfortunate review type - someone had edited out the spam and the answer was subsequently [deleted](https://askubuntu.com/admin/posts/timeline/677088).

The review system is not as clever as maybe it should be - its automated and basically you were shown the last answer and it would have been very difficult to know that someone had edited out the spam.

Fortunately we do have the ability to correct this sort of automated mess-ups.

You've been unbanned - welcome back to the review team.  Many thanks for keeping the site tidy.  Your contributions are very much valued.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that sometimes the audits are not good. But I did not fail to pass them really often. I think that 3-5 fails in a month is OK with hundreds of reviews.

Comment: I agree with Pilot6, I was banned too yesterday for 30 days after just one mistake, I see my biggest problem in flags denied by moderators telling `flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer` and then I am not very sure what to do with a "little" bad answer.

Comment: @Mike - if the answer is genuinely a comment (looks and smells like) then flag.  If the answer is a genuine attempt - even if its poor answer - downvote dont flag.   Downvoting should be the default position to deal with "little" bad answers.

Comment: Thanks, this is very good point.