# I was banned for 2 days from reviewing

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This question is related to many questions like [Why I am banned for reviewing?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14455/why-i-am-banned-for-reviewing/) but not duplicate.

Usually there are testing questions in Review. The system sometimes shows message like "*The system detected it as spam please review carefully*"  and sometimes not. Generally, in review I usually open the original post and then I will review the post.

Today I got one [question](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/468214) that is related to bash script, for which I felt U&L is good place, so I recommended to close. But unfortunately that was a highly voted question.

Immediately, I was banned for two days. The most astonished thing is ,one phrase "you have made too many incorrect reviews". As far as I remember I didn't make many.

- How do I find out how many mistakes I made?
- In flagging, till now I raised 632 flags: 581 helpful, 18 pending. Are there any similar statistics available for Review?

Please feel free to edit my title and content, if necessary.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake to close. Bash scripting is 100% on topic here as well: [Are bash/shell scripting questions on topic?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13807). Please don't vote to close shell scripting questions.

Comment: thank you @terdon,then what about my remaining two questions....I didn't made many mistakes in review.

Comment: I can't help with that, one of the mods will have to check.

Comment: -1 here?....may I know why?

Comment: Posted long ago on [meta.se]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192899/how-many-review-audits-did-i-fail

Comment: @Ravan downvotes on meta are used to signify either that i) the question is not useful or ii) that someone disagrees. They cost no reputation on meta though, so really, don't worry about it.

Comment: @terdon you are correct.but sometimes down vote hurts sometimes  not(irrespective of rep loss) .I appreciate it very much if  there is an explanation.(my opinion) =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the review audit/ban system doesn't have any good methods for reviewing your audits or seeing you stats. Even moderators don't have very good tools in this regard.

So your only real choice is stop failing audits ;)

I know that is easier than it sounds, but you will get it eventually. If you ever have any questions about an audit or review question feel free to pop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ask.

Comment: The audit/ban nonsense is what turned me off of being a regular contributor to AU. I show up here to do some reviews; sometimes, but,  the BS audits really dissuade me from participating more.

Comment: Additionally, I don't want to feel like I am being challenged when I am trying to improve the site. Part of community collaboration is not being treated like a suspect.