# Do audits and review bans exist only on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I am just curious to know whether we are the only site that tests its reviewers with audits and bans them if they fail too many audits?

- If **Yes**, why?
- If **No**, what are the other sites that act like this and why do only some sites do so?

As far as I know U&L doesn't behave that way.

Comment: How many audits did you fail in U&L?

Comment: FYI I didn't reviewed in U&L @muru =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small number of SE sites might have them turned off —I think we've had the opportunity to tune how much we use audits— but they're generally a good thing for the community.

If you are banned from review, I'm sure you probably have a very different view on audits. I personally hate failing single audits. However, review bans aren't handed out for single fails; you have to fail *many* audits. It's not a problem with the system, **it's a problem with *your* reviewing**.

The ban gives people an opportunity to step back and look at what they've done to earn the ban. In many cases that just means learning what is and isn't acceptable on the site.

Comment: thanks @Oli =) I respect the audit method.But(sorry) I afraid I am not agreeing with "fail many edits"(my opinion ). Also as you mentioned in last two lines ,ban gives people a chance to review their failed edits,but where one can get those statistics like which review they made mistake...how many...

Comment: There isn't a publicly available statistic. Mods can search up to 30 days on each queue and I'm sure SE staffers can do whatever they like by hassling the database manually. I can edit my answer to append a list of *your* audit failures if you're happy for me to do so in public.

Comment: I think it is generally expected that people take note when they fail each audit... Not leaving it until they're banned.

Comment: thanks =)..Aa far as I remember I got not more than 5...but I may wonder after seeing actual figures =).Yes sure,I'm pretty happy if you give my audit failures even in _public_ ,...

Comment: But that append should be [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14466/i-was-banned-for-2-days-from-reviewing) because I asked this Q out of curiosity =)