# Are the review ban thresholds really wrong?

Tags: discussion

Today I was banned again for 7 days this time.

[Last time](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14455/why-i-am-banned-for-reviewing) I was banned for 2 days because of an incorrect review sample.

[This time](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/478363) I voted Looks OK for a badly formatted answer that is theoretically correct, but lacks an explanation. Since it could be helpful I voted this way.

I know that the audits are needed, but it seems that the thresholds are wrong.

Comment: That's odd, considering that you're on of the people that has guided me on my path to 100+ reputation. Is it a glitch, or does someone have it out for you?

Comment: That is a kind of a glitch. The system selects not good samples for audits and almost immediately bans on a bad  guess.

Comment: I'm positive this is pretty much the same thing as flags: it matters how many you fail over a period of time to hit the threshold and how many times you hit the threshold in that period of time to determine the "punishment". If you just went below the threshold and go over it again in the same period you're "punished" harder.

Comment: On a side note, it's true that the audit system has some quirks, but to be fair that *was* a bad answer, it was just a list of unformatted commands without an explanation. Also on another side note, just try to edit the formatting makes you pass the audit automatically. So a suggestion is to always try to fix what's wrong, even if minor. The system will understand that you understood something is wrong and you want to do something about it.

Comment: @kos I did not know that. But the problem is that it is a correct set of commands. But my concern is that the threshold is too low ttaking in account that the audits are not always really good, like the last one I referred to. This one is more or less better.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the audits are bad sometimes. However honestly I wouldn't run a set of commands without a minimum explanation, I'm sure you had at least a doubt on that review. In that case you could have also left a comment asking the poster to expand their answer: that would have let you pass the audit as well, and also downvoting would have. The important thing is to show that you saw something, no matter how

Comment: I had a doubt. And this makes sense. I could comment or edit.

Comment: Or skip. If you aren't sure, you don't have to do *anything*.

Comment: @Oli I skip lot's of reviews. :-) But in this case the question was not good, but not incorrect. So I thought that there was no reason to delete it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've gone through all the audits you failed in the last 14 days (about ~5) and only found one blatantly wrong review ([this one](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/474903), if you're curious). All the others were either borderline or outright wrong (e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/478363) is an answer and should not have been deleted).

In light of this I have removed your review ban.

I'm a little worried that people are getting banned for doing the right thing. I haven't yet determined if this is because things are being deleted wrongly or the system just isn't good enough, but I will see what can be done about it.

Comment: Thanks. I am curious myself why I failed that one really wrong. It may be a kind of mis-click. You should know that my reviews are not too liberal at all ;-)

Comment: Anyway the thresholds look weird. I made >1000 reviews in the last two weeks. I passed lot's of audits. And this 0.5% is too tough, even if all were correct.